# Decompress BZIP - QNAP HBS 3 Backups

Tags: qnap

I'm using QNAP to backup to my DROPBOX account. It has the option to compress uploads in BZIP and requires you to decompress to use the files.  However, I can't find any program that will decompress it correctly.  It keeps all the filenames the same but compressed.

FILE.txt (QNAP) > FILE.txt (BZIP'd Dropbox)

In the notes

"Data is compressed using bzip. After compression, the data must be decompressed before it can be used."

QNAP Docs
https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/hybrid-backup-sync

Any ideas using windows to decompress?  Or linux if need be...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can use the "[QENC Decrypter](https://www.qnap.com.cn/en-in/utilities/enterprise)" to decompress it.